# Bot checking if the member has the role

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I have this on my code but when I execute the command twice (the name command, user, and role) it doesn't return this message. It keeps on saying "I added [role name] to [user]"

```
if (message.guild.members.cache.some(role => role.name)) {
  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('RANDOM')
    .setDescription(`${message.mentions.users.first()} has that role already!`);

    return message.channel.send(embed);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you save the code? Also, instead of

`if (message.guild.members.cache.some(role => role.name))`

do

`if (message.guild.members.cache.some(role => role.name === 'roleName')) //insert role name`.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: My bot is in multiple guilds. I'm pretty sure that wouldn't work